# Rails can't render polymorphic associations to XML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I render XML with an :include clause for a polymorphic association I have, it doesn't work. I end up with the XML returning the object pointers instead of the actual objects, like:

```
<posts>
   #<Comment:0x102ed1540>#<Comment:0x102ecaa38>#<Comment:0x102ec7fe0>#<Comment:0x102ec3cd8>
</posts>
```

Yet as_json works! When I render JSON with :include clause, the associations are rendered correctly and I get something like:

```
posts":[
{"type":"Comment","created_at":"2010-04-20T23:02:30-07:00","id":7,"content":"fourth comment"},
{"type":"Comment","created_at":"2010-04-20T23:02:26-07:00","id":6,"content":"third comment"}]
```

My current workaround is using XML builder, but I'm not too comfortable with that in the long run. Does anyone happen to know about this issue? I'm kind of in a catch-22 because while XML doesn't render the associations, as_json doesn't render in a kosher json format (returns an array rather than a list of hashes as proper json should) and the deserializer I'm using on the client side would require modification to parse the json correctly.

**edit**  I'm using 2.3.5 - also I am using the has_many_polymorphs gem for polymorphic has many :through, that may be causing an issue...

The model is that I have hangouts, and each hangout has many posts which are polymorphic to comments, photos, etc.

Controller code for XML: 
 format.xml  { render :xml => @hangouts.to_xml(:include => :users , :methods => :posts) }

Code for json is similar (in model):
def as_json(options)
    super(:include => :users, :methods => :posts)

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: jpartogi, bensie: I'm using 2.3.5 - also I am using the has_many_polymorphs gem for polymorphic has many :through, that may be causing an issue...

The model is that I have hangouts, and each hangout has many posts which are polymorphic to comments, photos, etc.

Controller code for XML: 
 format.xml  { render :xml => @hangouts.to_xml(:include => :users , :methods => :posts) }


Code for json is similar (in model):
def as_json(options)
    super(:include => :users, :methods => :posts)

Comment: In addition, I can bypass has_many_polymorphs and just define :comments, :photos methods to include in to_xml - while hangout.comments and hangout.photos works fine in the console, the xml still returns object points. Strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Objective Resource google groups, seems like this is a feature that doesn't exist in Rails, so I ended up just using XML builder

Answer (score 0):

I could get this line to return the complete nested XML

```
format.xml { render :xml => @post.to_xml(:include => [ :links, :assets])}
```

like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<post>
  <body>testing.../body>
  <created-at type="datetime">2010-09-21T06:19:13Z</created-at>
  <id type="integer">1</id>
  <title>1</title>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2010-09-21T06:19:13Z</updated-at>

  <links type="array"/>
  <assets type="array">
    <asset>
      <attachable-id type="integer">1</attachable-id>
      <attachable-type>Post</attachable-type>
      <created-at type="datetime">2010-09-21T06:19:13Z</created-at>
      <data-content-type>image/jpeg</data-content-type>

      <data-file-name>IMG00017-20100906-1226.jpg</data-file-name>
      <data-file-size type="integer">0</data-file-size>
      <id type="integer">1</id>
      <updated-at type="datetime">2010-09-21T06:19:13Z</updated-at>
    </asset>
  </assets>
</post>
```

Here is our model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :assets, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many    :links, :as => :linkable, :dependent => :destroy
...
```

Link Model

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :linkable, :polymorphic => true
...
```

Asset Model

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
...
```

In here, assets and links are not bound to any particular model. In the current usage, they are used in Post. Later on other models can use them.

is that what you are trying to achieve?